# Implementing Delta Time (In Seconds) into Velocity

Tags: c++, sdl, game-physics

Using C++, SDL2, and Vulkan, I'm trying to implement delta time into my game movement by multiplying movement speed by delta time like so:

```
velocity += speed * dt;
```

I've got this code below which apparently calculates delta time `dt`, but I don't really understand much of it and what I need to modify in order to be able to update the `velocity` by pixels per second.

EDIT: `SDL_GetTicks()` returns the current time by milliseconds.

```
deltaTime = (SDL_GetTicks() - lastTime) * (TARGET_FPS / 1000.f);

if (deltaTime > TARGET_DELTATIME)
    deltaTime = TARGET_DELTATIME;
    
lastTime = SDL_GetTicks();
```

With a given `TARGET_FPS` (lets say 60 for now), and a `speed` of 50 pixels per second, how can I update the `velocity` correctly?

Comment: You are mixing terms. Speed x time = distance travelled. Velocity is a combination fo speed and direction. At least in terms of physics.

Comment: You could also [fix your timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/), and never think about the delta again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never change the velocity, instead let your physics calculations include delta time as a component. In general, multiply by (delta_since_last_frame/arbitrary_constant_you_tune).

EDIT*
For example:
position += velocity * (delta * ARBITRARY_TUNING_CONSTANT); It's tempting to set ARBITRARY_TUNING_CONSTANT to TARGET_FPS/1000.0f, which you can, but set it to whatever lets you set your velocity values to something that feels intuitive to you.

Define a sort of base velocity value, for example let's say you want a velocity of 10.0 to represent moving at 50 px per second. Then set arbitrary_constant_you_tune to make this true. (the arbitrary constant is CONSTANT always, just set once during program initialization or config). Also once you really write it in code, use multiplication rather than division (e.g. prefer 0.2 to 1/5) because multiplication is faster to compute.

One nuance to this: be aware that the game physics will be slightly different for people at different frame rates if you use delta time in a simple manner like this. For example, maximum jump height will be different, 2 games running side-by-side at different frame rates will show a different course of events, etc. Just be aware of this as you tune your game physics and game logic

Comment: So when I apply velocity to position, would I do something like this: `position += velocity * otherCalculations * deltaTime`? Also, how do I incorporate FPS into delta time?

Comment: Yeah, position += velocity * (delta_time * ARBITARY_TUNING_CONSTANT)

Comment: Ok thanks, I just have one more question. Do I keep velocity unchanged/constant no matter what? Even if I add other calculations such as friction, acceleration,  etc?

Comment: @Fognam1n Only change velocity when the intended velocity of the entity changes (by that I mean, the velocity that the character is "trying" to move at, like if the player holds sprint and is trying to move at sprint speed now). Let the final position update be determined by logic and calculations (so don't think of velocity as just the difference in position for the current frame).

Comment: @Fognam1n there can be exceptions though, like if you want to smoothly accelerate or decelerate, then you need to possibly add some kind of maxVelocity or targetVelocity parameters to handle that, in which case you'll be changing your velocity parameter based on your computed acceleration for that frame.

Comment: Oh ok, I got it now. Thanks a lot, Alex!